# iFrame overlay Silverlight 5

Tags: html, silverlight

I have got a problem in my Silverlight-Application.
There is an iFrame displayed at my XAML view. When I open now a childwindow control (sample Messagebox), the iFrame is still overlaying the MessageBox. I need to put the child-window over the iFrame. Can anyone help me?

Best regards, Patrik

[image: Overlay]

Comment: Xaml cannot define iFrames, it's kinda hard to understand what you mean...

Comment: Hey sorry for my bad description. I have add my iFrame via JavaScript into the Silverlight-Page.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but I will assume that what you have is a Silverlight application with an iFrame on top (defined in the hosting HTML file) containing some other content. If this is your scenario you are out of luck. What you are asking is basically for the Silverlight application to take a small part of itself (the child window), move that part outside of its own confines and then render that small part on top of something else in the browser.

Comment: Hey Henrik,
thank you for answering. I think you understand me in the right way. But are there no possibilities to overlay the childwindow above the iFrame? I have add a screenshot. More I can not unfortunately show.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It is a bit like asking an html page to take one of its <div>s and render it on top of Microsoft Word in Windows. A Silverlight app will always be limited to its own confines. The only option I can think of is to execute some javascript in the hosting html page that finds the iFrame and hides it, leaving the childwindow visible. This would have to be done when you show the childwindow, or possibly on GotFocus. Then when the childwindow is hidden you would have to find the iFrame and show it again.

Comment: Ok thats a option. My iFrame is in a control that will be open if a user clicks on a button. When that control is visible, the iFrame is also open but the user has the opinion to open childwindows. Is there any possibility to bind an event to my iFrame control that triggers if any childwindow is open?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but it will probably be difficult to get the iFrame to listen to events from your Silverlight child windows. Instead I think you will have to call your js functions from within Silverlight whenever a child window opens/closes. Here is a short intro to communication between Silverlight and JS: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/08/tip-of-the-day-15-communicating-between-javascript-amp-silverlight.aspx